# ui-select selecticize templates not found

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, selectize.js, angular-ui-select

I am trying to use angular ui-select in my application, it worked just fine, except I wanted to change the theme from bootstrap to selecticize, that is when i got these errors:

[image]

I have no idea what to do i have two bootstrap files i tried loading both because i read one has templates and the other does not but but didn't solve my issue either.

1. ui-bootstrap.min.js
2. ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Include only

> ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js

It has templates as string inside it as well as all the functionalities. So leave out the first one and try. Hope it will work :)

Comment: I just did but the errors are still there, meaning selecticize/ui-select is loading from somewhere else

Comment: Ya, then I also think so. Just check it out.